# Vaadin8 Bug with Grids - cannot set sour

Tags: java, vaadin

I have a possible bug with Vaadin8 Grid - it does not display any data at all nor does it output any error. It will not display any data when I input List<> in it through setData

Here is the code for UI:
    @Theme("mytheme")
    public class MyUI extends UI {

```
private BankeriClient bankeriClient = new BankeriClient();

@Override
protected void init(VaadinRequest vaadinRequest) {
    final VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();
    final HorizontalLayout buttonLayout = new HorizontalLayout();

    final TextField nameField = new TextField();
    final TextField surnameField = new TextField();
    final DateField dateField = new DateField();
    final TextField addressField = new TextField();
    final TextField dollarsField = new TextField();    

    Response response = bankeriClient.findAll_JSON(Response.class);
    List<Bankeri> listBankeri = response.readEntity(new GenericType<List<Bankeri>>() {});
    Grid<Bankeri> grid = new Grid<>(Bankeri.class);
    grid.addColumn(Bankeri::getJmeno).setCaption("First name").setEditorComponent(
            nameField,
            Bankeri::setJmeno
    );
    grid.addColumn(Bankeri::getPrijmeni).setCaption("Surname").setEditorComponent(
            surnameField,
            Bankeri::setPrijmeni
    );
    grid.addColumn(Bankeri::getLocalDatum_narozeni).setCaption("Date of birth").setEditorComponent(
            dateField,
            Bankeri::setLocalDatum_narozeni
    );
    grid.addColumn(Bankeri::getAdresa).setCaption("Address").setEditorComponent(
            addressField,
            Bankeri::setAdresa
    );
    grid.addColumn(Bankeri::getStringPenize).setCaption("Dollars").setEditorComponent(
            dollarsField,
            Bankeri::setStringPenize
    );
    grid.setData(listBankeri);
    grid.getEditor().setEnabled(true);
    grid.getEditor().setSaveCaption("Save");
    grid.getEditor().setCancelCaption("Cancel");

    final Button addBanker = new Button();
    addBanker.setCaption("Přidej bankéře");
    addBanker.addClickListener(e -> {
        Bankeri toAdd = new Bankeri();
        listBankeri.add(toAdd);
        grid.getDataProvider().refreshAll();
    });

    final Button saveBanker = new Button();
    saveBanker.setCaption("Ulož data bankéřů");
    saveBanker.addClickListener(e -> {
        for(Bankeri banker : listBankeri) {
            bankeriClient.create_JSON(banker);
        }
    });

    buttonLayout.addComponents(addBanker, saveBanker);
    layout.addComponents(grid, buttonLayout);

    setContent(layout);
}

@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/*", name = "MyUIServlet", asyncSupported = true)
@VaadinServletConfiguration(ui = MyUI.class, productionMode = false)
public static class MyUIServlet extends VaadinServlet {
}
}
```

As for the object I'm trying to display: It's an entity class
I'm using: GlassFish 4.1.0, netbeans.
Thank you so much for any help!

With regards, Jan

Answer (score 0):

Solved it! setItems instead of setData was the correct answer!

Comment: Can you expand this Answer a bit more, to be of help to posterity?

Comment: setData(..) is an ancient method that just piggy bags object with component. As stated in JavaDoc, the stock components do not use this data themselves.